# Pattern not matching in Erlang

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching, gen-server

I'm making this call:

```
add(Login, Pass, Role) ->
  gen_server:call(?SERVER, {add, Login, Pass, Role}).
```

and I expect it to match with:

```
handle_call(State, {add, Login, Pass, Role}) ->
  io:format("add ~n"),
  Db = State#state.db,
  case lists:keyfind(Login, 1, Db) of
    false->
      io:format("add - reg new ~n"),
      {reply, registered, State#state{db=[{Login, erlang:md5(Pass), Role, ""}|Db]}};
     {Key, Result}-> 
      {reply, invalid_params, Db}  
  end.
```

but it always goes to:

```
handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
  io:format("undef ~n"),
  Reply = ok,
  {reply, Reply, State}.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour seems valid,

`handle_call` has such spec:

```
-spec(handle_call(Request :: term(), From :: {pid(), Tag :: term()},
    State :: #state{}) ->
  {reply, Reply :: term(), NewState :: #state{}} |
  {reply, Reply :: term(), NewState :: #state{}, timeout() | hibernate} |
  {noreply, NewState :: #state{}} |
  {noreply, NewState :: #state{}, timeout() | hibernate} |
  {stop, Reason :: term(), Reply :: term(), NewState :: #state{}} |
  {stop, Reason :: term(), NewState :: #state{}}).
```

If you can take a look here
http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_call-3

Also, for otp default behaviours, it would be the best, as a start, to use templates. For gen_server eg https://gist.github.com/kevsmith/1211350

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

In a module using the `gen_server` behaviour, the `handle_call` callback function should take three arguments.  However, you have defined two different functions, `handle_call/2` and `handle_call/3`.  (In Erlang, functions that have the same name but take different numbers of arguments are considered different functions.)

Since the `gen_server` module only looks for `handle_call/3` and ignores `handle_call/2`, your "undef" function is always called.

To fix this, change the function to take an (ignored) second argument, and put the request first and the state last:

```
handle_call({add, Login, Pass, Role}, _From, State) ->
```

and change the `end.` to `end;` — `.` separates different functions, while `;` separates different clauses of the same function.

Comment: `State` is the last parameter: it's `handle_call(Req, _From, State)`.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice that... Fixed now.

Comment: handle_cast/2 takes 2 arguments, handle_call/3 always takes 3, The gen_event has handle_call/2